# the store and forward mechanism transmission delay

Tags: computer-networks

In a computer network, the store and forward mechanism is used. In this mechanism, the packet is sent from one system to the next along the network path, and in the second system, the complete packet received is checked and then sent to the next system in the network. This mechanism is quite similar to the behavior of a pipeline in computer architecture. In other words, each jump (distance from one system to the next system in the network) can be considered as a stage that its task must be done and systems along the path can be considered similar to buffers that must store the result of the stages. Accordingly, answer the following questions.

Considering a network consisting of 2 source and destination systems and 3 intermediate routers. The transfer rate in all parts of this network is 10 Mbps. We plan to send a 100 MB file as a message from the source system to the destination system on this network.

Based on the formulas in the pipeline and with the help of basic network calculations for transmission delay,

I want to  show that to send this message, fragmenting the message to the size of 1500 bytes and then sending them, how much acceleration in transmitting this file from the source
system will be the destination system, depending on when the whole file is sent at once. In this case, suppose the fragmentation of the message does not involve additional costs and overheads
(header or trailer).

Comment: (I can't understand `how much acceleration in transmitting [a 100 MB] file from the source system will be the destination system, depending on when the whole file is sent at once`, even substituting *depending on* by *as compared to*: how can any amount of acceleration be a system?) (If your "native tongue" isn't English, try having a phrase you're not sure about translated to your favourite language. And or vice-versa.)

Comment: When a message is fragmented, each fragment needs an information overhead in the form of multiple headers in the network. Suppose each packet adds x bytes of data overhead.

Comment: In this case, what is the optimal size of packets (including headers and data payloads) for transmission in this network? The most optimal mode is the minimum delay of complete file / message transfer from the source system to the destination system

Comment: [`Suppose each packet adds x bytes of data overhead`](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/145876/the-store-and-forward-mechanism-transmission-delay?noredirect=1#comment307862_145876) contradicts [`suppose the fragmentation of the message does not involve additional costs and overheads`](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/145876/19966) in the question body: is this one more question, a separate one?

Comment: yes it is i aim second one.

Comment: i would not use this model to optimize packet size. there are other issues involved. (1) hardware capabilities that limit maximum packet size (aka MTU). (2) probability of errors - how many packets are affected and need to be retransmitted (3) fairness - network is shared between several entities transmitting files, if one of the entities occupies the transmission channel with large packet, other entities cannot access it (4) related to 1 are physical resources on network devices to store packets (although probably not an issue now)

Comment: and also, in order to accelerate transmission, you will need to be able to send different packets along different paths. If you consider the same path, there is no way that fragmentation accelerates anything.